# Invoice amount is not correct after generating invoice magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice

I just clicked on create invoice button and nothing else but magento calculation shows wrong amount in invoice.

[image: invoice section pic]

[image: Default section]

i don't know how total paid is only 499.50. Can anyone help me, maybe there's something I'm missing. In this pic.

[image: cart price rule]

[image: cart rule]

**Update :** This issue is solved as it caused by some other extension which extended the invoice system.

Comment: Looks like some sort of price rule is applied, that yields the discount being calculated. Could you check that?

Comment: @mizuti  yes i just checked every thing is as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved as it caused by some other extension which extended the invoice system.

So to save others time , i accepting this as my answer.